# Append text to the end of the tomcat.conf

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra

I am using the Opscode Tomcat cookbook along with my own that I've created. I need to append a loop to the end of the /etc/default/tomcat{version} file and I have looked into using partials but I'm not sure how I would apply that through my own cookboook (our company has a policy of creating our own cookbooks that pull in external cookbooks as a reference).

I think perhaps the Template resource would do it but I've also been told that Providers might be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `line` cookbook which was created by a Chef, Inc. employee for dealing with minor file changes:

https://github.com/someara/line-cookbook

Examples:

```
append_if_no_line "make sure a line is in dangerfile" do
  path "/tmp/dangerfile"
  line "HI THERE I AM STRING"
end

replace_or_add "spread the love" do
  path "/some/file"
  pattern "Why hello there.*"
  line "Why hello there, you beautiful person, you."
end

delete_lines "remove hash-comments from /some/file" do
  path "/some/file"
  pattern "^#.*"
end

add_to_list "add entry to a list"
  path "/some/file"
  pattern "People to call: "
  delim [","]
  entry "Bobby"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this not very elegant solution;

```
ruby_block "insert_line" do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/hosts")
    file.insert_line_if_no_match("/www.example.com/", "www.example.com")
    file.write_file
  end
end
```